# Is there a Bayesian analogue to a simultaneous confidence band?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, credible-interval

A simultaneous confidence band denotes the probability

$$p \big(\hat{f}(x) - w(\hat{f}(x)) \le f(x) \le \hat{f}(x) + w(\hat{f}(x))  \ \ \forall x \big)=1-\alpha$$

where $f$ a function of $x$, $\hat{f}$ and estimator for the value of $f$ at $x$, and $w(\hat{f}(x))$ an estimated interval length at $x$, see also [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands).

**Is there an existing analogue definition in Bayesian statistics and how is the resulting band estimated?** (Using the posterior or posterior predictive distribution.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a prior distribution $\pi$ on a functional space and observations about the function values at some points, or noisy observations of the function itself, the posterior distribution $\pi(\cdot|\mathcal{D})$ can be used to derive an HPD region,
$$\left\{f\in\mathcal{F}\,,\ \pi(f |\mathcal{D})\ge k_\alpha\right\}$$
at least in principle since the derivation may prove too complex in a general situation.

For instance,

Breth, M. (1978) [Bayesian confidence bands for estimating a function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2958568?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Annals of Statistics Vol. 6, No. 3, pp. 649-657

seems to address this problem.

Comment: Is it possible to simulate this region using the samples from a posterior?

Comment: Not that I know of, because the samples are functions. Except by considering the convex envelope of these functions, providing a conservative HPD region.

Comment: This paper seems relevant in this regard. I wonder if this has been extended to the multivariate case. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9876.00053/pdf

Comment: I am not sure; can't we consider $f(x)$ a bivariate parameter if $x$ is binary?

Comment: Yes, but this changes everything in your question!